# Textbox validation: Get control of/duplicate the system validation border?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding

I'm wanting to validate Textbox entries for an application and provide both visual and verbal feedback in the case of an error. I'd like the normal Textbox border behavior you get from wpf when using `ValidationRules` or `INotifyDataError`, then in a separate TextBlock display an error message. Standard stuff. I've got a few ways to approach this but each one is giving me problems.

`ValidationRules` seems like the easiest system-based approach. My problem here is binding the error message to the separate TextBlock. Most examples use content presenters or error templates, but is there no simple way to bind to a `ValidationResult` directly? **(Question 1)**

`INotifyDataError` being the more modern approach is nice in theory, but it seems wayyy too complicated for what I'm doing.

However, the simplest way I have found is validating directly in the property's setter in the Viewmodel. Something like this:

```
private string _fileName;
public string FileName
{
   get {return _fileName;}
   set
   {
       _fileName = value;
       if(String.IsEmptyOrNull(value))
       {
           FileNameError = "File must have a name.";
       }
       else
       {
           FileNameError = null;
       }
       RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

private string _fileNameError;
public string FileNameError
{
   get {return _fileNameError;}
   set
   {
       _fileNameError = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged();
   }
}
```

Then, to show an error, I can bind 2x to `FileNameError`: Once to display the text in the TextBlock, and the other through a converter (checking for !null) to show the red border around the TextBox.

The problem here the way WPF does the red border is much better; it appears to be its own element rather than an actual border. When I try my StringToBorderBrush converter, the border's thickness reduces the TextBox size, so things no longer line up. The double whammy is that by setting the BorderBrush to transparent, I lose the TextBox's default border and focus border which I'd like to keep.

So is there a way to either duplicate what WPF is doing with the border, or to somehow control it with a property? I would think this would be possible because something has to call it when it is shown with `ValidationRules` or `INotifyDataError`, right? **(Question 2)**

Comment: It is probably best to use `IDataErrorInfo`/`INotifyDataError` than to replicate default validation error template by yourself.

Comment: @sthotakura: Thank you. I find them both rather confusing, to be honest. Like why do we need the extra steps of creating Dictionary items when the error messages will all be supplied by hardcoded strings? Do you know of any source that actually explains the interface and implements it simply? The common examples tend to have elements of "look at how good of a programmer I am" (for example, locks, async errors, etc) that make it hard for the beginner to really trace what's happening at the core.

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-validation-logic-on-custom-objects)

Comment: @sthotakura: Thank you so much! Along with a simple to understand IDataErrorInfo example, hidden in that page was the answer to Question 1. To bind the error content to a separate TextBlock you need to bind to `(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent` with the `ElementName` set to the name of the TextBox. Now its working how I want! Cheers!